# How to put an individual USB port to sleep?

Tags: windows-7, usb, sleep, hard-drive

I have a few external drives that I don't always use and want to be able to have them shutdown when I am not using them. They shutdown when the computer goes into sleep mode but I would like to be able to make them shutdown (and power up) without putting the whole computer to sleep.

So I was wondering if there is a way to make a USB device think the port its plugged into is asleep in Windows 7 x64. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Is it reasonable to just use the built in secure removal feature?

Answer (score 1):

USB ports can be disabled via the Device Manager or registry edit. Disabling the USB ports will put the USB device to "sleep." However, the downfall is it requires a reboot after enabling or disabling the device.

Another solution that only works on external USB hard drives (and I assume pin drives) is putting your drive offline. The drive will not be accessible, but it will still receive power. The how-to steps are below.

#### How to Switch a Drive to Offline and Online - Windows 7

1. Start
2. Type: `diskmgmt.msc`
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Find the drive from the **bottom half** of the MMC
5. **Right Click** the drive
6. Select *Offline* or *Online*

*Repeat steps to reverse your actions*